# Rails, route mapping not matching the correct action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to route the following URL:

```
/shop/{category_id}/{product_id}/
```

to a controller action called 'product'

I've got this in my routes:

```
match "/shop/:category/:id" => "shop#product"
```

and i've got link_to's as follows:

```
link_to_unless_current "#{t('murals')}", url_for(:controller => 'shop', :category => 'walls', :id => 'murals')
```

When the urls are output, they are:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/shop?category=walls&id=murals
```

instead of the desired:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/shop/walls/murals
```

if i switch the route, so it goes to:

```
match "/shop/:category/:id" => "shop#index"
```

this works, but it's not the right action.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I hardcode the URL in, so set it to:

    url_for('/shop/prints-canvases/canvases')

this will then map to the product controller and the url shows properly. So, looks like the problem is the output of url_for rather than routing. Is there a way to force the url_for to use proper REST structure over the horrible paramed route its outputting?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "#{t('murals')}", custom_path(:category => 'walls', :id => 'murals') %>

match "/shop/:category/:id" => "shop#product", :as => :custom
```